# jp2:rate gives unexpected output file size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Heyho,

i am using imagemagick 6.8. (2015-03-20) and I tried to convert a .pgm file to a .jp2 file. The output file should be smaller by the factor specified in the jp2:rate=x option, but it does not seem to work.

I am using this command

```
convert input.pgm -define jp2:rate=20.0 output.jp2
```

But the resulting file, output.jp2, is bigger than expected (Only compression rate 6 instead of the expected 20)

Could somebody explain this to me please?

Comment: A couple of thoughts... the compression you achieve will depend on the contents of the file. Secondly, your input file is greyscale, and your output file presumably contains red, green and blue channels so you have put JPEG2000 at a considerable disadvantage from the outset.

Comment: I'm trying the same thing and encountering the same results. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26472 reports the same kind of bug. Were you using Mac OS X? I am, and I suspect this is a platform-specific bug.

Comment: Imagemagick switched from using Jasper delegate library for JP2000 to OpenJpeg delegate library starting at version 6.8.8-2. So comparing results from an older release to a newer one will be comparing results from two different JP2000 libraries. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php for JP2000 defines.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for ImageMagick Version 6.7.7-10 2017-07-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org

```
convert input.pgm -define jp2:rate=0.05 #not 20.0
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation about your answer. Why is it 0.05 (1/20) instead of 20.0. Usually code-only answers without description do not attract upvotes.

Comment: Imagemagick switched from using Jasper delegate library for JP2000 to OpenJpeg delegate library starting at version 6.8.8-2. So comparing results from an older release to a newer one will be comparing results from two different JP2000 libraries. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php for JP2000 defines.